# Any book recommendations for improving my T-SQL kung fu?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Anyone have any recommendations on a good book to improve my T-SQL kung fu?  I have been looking Joe at some of Joe Celko's books, but are there better ones out there?  I need to develop a better understanding of JOINS and some of the other more advanced topics.  I appreciate any recommendations.

Comment: The Celko books are ... interesting (and worth a read; he really likes his sets) ... but not really "T-SQL"-specific, which is what I guess is the focus now? (T-SQL sometimes dresses up like SQL ;-)

Comment: [TSQL Challenge](http://beyondrelational.com/blogs/tc/default.aspx), otherwise read SQL Server related questions on SO ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend *SQL Server 2008 for Developers*. Great book you can a lot of advanced topics from. A must read for db developers.

You can find the book [here](http://www.murach.com/books/sql8/index.htm).  The authors are Joel Murach and Bryan Syverson.

Comment: Author(s)?? Link to a website???

Comment: I will post this on a site that lets the user solicit opinions from the community.